# Why hostname -f gives me subdomain back when only domain is in /etc/hostname?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, hostname

In my /etc/hostname (Ubuntu 14.04) file I have:

```
pavel@subdomain:~$ cat /etc/hostname
example.ru
```

But when I run:

```
hostname -f
```

it shows:

```
pavel@subdomain:~$ hostname -f
subdomain.example.ru
```

It possibly (100%) affects my postfix configuration, when I'm trying to configure it as send-only SMTP-server and it sends messages with "pavel@subdomain.domain.ru" sender address.

How and where to avoid subdomain in my case? Thank you!

Comment: To solve your `Postfix` issue, you might want to take a look at [Postfix Address Rewriting - Masquerade](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#masquerade). I can't tell you this is *the* solution to use, but it worked perfectly when I had the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 1):

The hostname should contain the name of the server, for example athena.zertux.net is my subdomain, in the hostname i would put athena.

The `/etc/hosts` file can contain a mapping of IP address to a domain/subdomain.

In your case:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       example.ru
```

If you need a specific IP for your domain name, you can change 127.0.0.1

Comment: But what if my domain name (e.g. hostname.ru) should be aliased to the virtual machine itself?

Comment: You can add that in the /etc/hosts file

Answer (score 1):

`hostname -f` resolves the name given by `hostname` into an IP, and then does a reverse lookup on that address to get the name to return to you.

In your specific case, your DNS (or `/etc/hosts`) is turning `example.ru` into an IP address, which then reverses back into `subdomain.example.ru`, so that's where the name is coming from.